# C# DTSearch TypeInitializationException In Options

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dtsearch

I have a legacy C# project that uses dtsearch with the dtSearchNetApi2 NuGet Package. I am currently using VS 2015 with .NET 4.5 target. When I attempt to make a dtSearch.Engine.Options object I get a TypeInitializationException. I have tried a few things and changed my code to find out where the issue is really coming from.

Orignal:

```
_dtSearchOptions = new Options{ FieldFlags = FieldFlags.dtsoFfSkipDocumentProperties |
                                                       FieldFlags.dtsoFfSkipFilenameFieldPath |
                                                       FieldFlags.dtsoFfSkipFilenameField};
```

I thought maybe there was a problem with the FieldFlags, so I removed them and everything else to just make a normal Options object.

```
_dtSearchOptions = new Options();
```

But this also gives me the TypeInitializationException. 
The inner exception for this says that the exception comes from LoadEngine() with the following exact message

```
InnerException: 
   HResult=-2147024894
   Message=dten600.dll
   Source=dtSearchNetApi2
   StackTrace:
        at LoadEngine()
        at ApiInitializer..ctor()
        at ApiInitializer..cctor()
```

Any ideas of what is going wrong here? This is legacy code and is currently being used, so I believe this must have to do with my VS or setup and not the code itself.

Comment: `-2147024894` is `0x80070002`, which is `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)`. So my wild and unfounded guess is that the code is trying to load `dten600.dll` dynamically, but failing to do so (or else the unmanaged code is hitting a `FILE_NOT_FOUND` deeper down the chain, due to some other missing dependency). Verify this DLL is present and in the search path. If necessary, use [`procmon`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) to find the actual call resulting in `FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: would I need to add this dll as a reference?

Comment: Almost certainly not -- it just needs to be loadable from somewhere. I'm not familiar with how dtSearch is installed or how the NuGet package finds it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try to hunt that down then.

Comment: looks like you are right. That file isn't referenced correctly or is missing.

Comment: You have to register dten600.dll